# Change option of natbib in AIP

Tags: natbib, revtex

I really want to have my references generated with BibTeX like [1], [2] instead of <sup>1</sup>, <sup>2</sup> in the AIP class which uses `revtex4-1.cls`.

I guess I need to change the `super` option of the package `natbib`.

I tried

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{square,sort,comma,numbers}{natbib}
```

but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you are using REVTEX then presumably you are submitting to the AIP. In this case _do not_ mess with the formatting: it has been set up by the editorial office and isn't really something you can change.

Comment: No, I don't submit to the AIP, I just want a nice template for my report :) 

I found a hack which works: `\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{[#1] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what you have when you import AIP from ShareTeX:

[image: AIP]

I wanted to replace <sup>1</sup> with [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXRA6.png):

[image: AIP modified]

To do this you need to add `\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{[#1] }` before `\begin{document}` and then use `[\onlinecite{label}]` instead of `\cite{label}`.

Answer (score 3):

Which AIP journal are you planning to submit to?

Here is what you should generally use:

```
\documentclass[aip, ***, preprint]{revtex4-1}
```

where *** is a class option which says which aip journal are you submitting to:

```
Journal                            class option (***)
Appl. Phys. Lett.                  apl
Biomicrouidics                     bmf
Chaos                              cha
J. Appl. Phys.                     jap
J. Chem. Phys.                     jcp
J. Math. Phys.                     jmp
J. Renewable Sustainable Energy    rse
Phys. Fluids                       pof
Phys. Plasmas                      pop
Rev. Sci. Instrum.                 rsi
```

Here `jcp` is the default.

Then use the following commands towards the end of your manuscript:

```
\bibliographystyle{aipnum4-1}
\bibliography{References}
```

You can control the `bibliographystyle` further by reading manuals named 'aipguide4-1.pdf' and '[auguide4-1.pdf](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://publish.aps.org/files/revtex/auguide4-1.pdf&ei=IYHRUpr8IcSxrAfIr4Eo&usg=AFQjCNG8zKO95VZ6EFYQ2naEfBVw2wxs1g&sig2=R2yGcfLNOXc3l9W8VFyENw&bvm=bv.59026428,d.bmk)'

Comment: I already tried each journal but that does not modify anything in the section _References_. Even with `\bibliographystyle{aipnum4-1}` it stays the same. The only way I found is `\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{[#1] }`

Comment: Since you need [1], which I don't recall is used by any AIP or APS journal (correct me if I am wrong here), I deduce that you are trying to do something different. Are you writing a book? Which journal do you plan to submit to? I suggest that instead of \cite{} you may want to use \onlinecite{}, \citenum or \citealp.

Comment: In fact APS journal is using [1] but not AIP! I am just writing a report for academic purpose. As I prefer AID to APS, I just want to change the references' style. Yes you are right : instead of `\cite{label}` you have to use `[\onlinecite{label}]`.

Comment: Which APS journal has that style? Also, please 'upvote' any answers or 'discussions' if you think that they deserve the visibility for future readers.

Comment: Just replace `aip` with `aps` in the sample of AIP journal from ShareTeX and you will see references with style [1], [2]...