# Change formatting of date from '(Dated: \today)' to '\today' in revtex4-1

Tags: revtex

In AIP template using `revtex4-1.cls` I want to renew correctly the command `\date{}`

[image]

I just want to replace the output by `\today` instead of `(Dated: \today)`.

What is the best way to do it in this sample of code ?

```
\documentclass[
 aip,
 jmp,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 reprint,
]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math

\begin{document}

\title[Sample title]{Sample Title}% Force line breaks with \\
\thanks{Footnote to title of article.}

\author{A. Author}
 \altaffiliation[Also at ]{Physics Department, XYZ University.}%Lines break automatically or can be forced with \\
\author{B. Author}%
 \email{Second.Author@institution.edu.}
\affiliation{ 
Authors' institution and/or address%\\This line break forced with \textbackslash\textbackslash
}%

\date{\today}% It is always \today, today,
             %  but any date may be explicitly specified

\begin{abstract}
Your abstract
\end{abstract}

\pacs{Valid PACS appear here}% PACS, the Physics and Astronomy
                             % Classification Scheme.
\keywords{Suggested keywords}%Use showkeys class option if keyword
                              %display desired
\maketitle

\begin{quotation}
Your lead paragraph
\end{quotation}

\section{First Heading}

Article content \cite{small}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg I guess he wants the string »(Dated ... )« to disappear.

Comment: Look at the duplicate question: in an answer, you find how to change the "Dated: " to "Datum: ". Just type `\def\Dated@name{}` instead. But if you want to submit the document, *don't* remove "Dated:".

Comment: As [@JosephWright](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153559/change-option-of-natbib-in-aip#comment350729_153559) mentioned before, journal templates are templates for a reason.

Comment: @Johannes_B My goal is to modify this template for an academic report. Can you tell me why I should not adapt it to my own needs?

Comment: Publishing for a journal requires consistency. If you do not want to publish it, you can adapt it to your own needs and are free to change the former template to an actually nice looking document. AFAIC the looks of the journal aren't that great.

Comment: @egreg While the two questions are very close, your answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122274/renaming-date-in-revtex4 doesn't show how to remove the parentheses around "Dated: ...". I don't think the question should be closed yet.

Comment: @Jubobs You're right. I'll retract the vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you want to do this. I'd never use the `revtex4-1` class for any other purpose than a submission. In this case, modifying the layout is useless.

However, here's how you can do.

```
\documentclass[
 aip,
 jmp,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 reprint,
]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% \frontmatter@RRAP@format is responsible for the parentheses
\patchcmd{\frontmatter@RRAP@format}{(}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\frontmatter@RRAP@format}{)}{}{}{}
\renewcommand\Dated@name{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\title{Sample Title}% Force line breaks with \\
\thanks{Footnote to title of article.}

\author{A. Author}
\affiliation{Authors' institution and/or address}

\date{Ides of March, 44 BC}

\begin{abstract}
Your abstract
\end{abstract}

\pacs{Valid PACS appear here}

\keywords{Suggested keywords}

\maketitle

\begin{quotation}
Your lead paragraph
\end{quotation}

\section{First Heading}

Article content \cite{small}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was looking through the `revtex4-1` source code and I couldn't find where those darned parentheses were coming from!

Comment: @Jubobs The command is well hidden in `aip4-1.rtx`