# Modify \date in aip document class

Tags: document-classes, datetime

I am working with a sharelatex template for AIP and use this document class command:

```
\documentclass[%
 aip,
 jmp,%
 amsmath,amssymb,
%preprint,%
 reprint,%
%author-year,%
%author-numerical,%
]{revtex4-1}
```

when I give the command `\date{sth}` I get in the pdf: (Dated: sth). How can I change the way `\date{sth}` displays the  date? For instance I would like it to be: (The date: sth), or without parenthesis.

Thanks for your help. Sorry if my language is not precise.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Change formatting of date from `(Dated: \today)` to `\today` in `revtex4-1`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153607/5764)

Comment: cheers @Werner Should I delete the question? Maybe the title might be helpful for other people.

Comment: Note that the usual reason to use this class is for journal or conference submission. In that case, you ought not change the format. Otherwise, it is better to use a more flexible class designed to be customised.

Comment: Duplicates are good, so leave it.

Comment: Nah. You can leave it and it will become a pointer, which can be useful for people searching, as you say. (Given how hard it is to find stuff on this site, people need all the help they can get!)